# Getting Locality from array of Entry objects. Using NodeGeocoder reverse function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase

I am trying to get the locality or in other words, the name of administrative unit that is tied to the postal code. I went through all the fields in the entry object and could not find what I needed.

```
const res : NodeGeocoder.Entry[] = await geocoder.reverse({lat:lat,lon:lng})

const zipcode = res[0].zipcode!
const country = res[0].country!
const city = res[0].city || undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what was the problem. The entry object provided in the geocoder typings does not contain neighborhood, but the response object from the geocoder actually does contain that information. To be able to get that info, I extended the Entry interface like so:

```
import { Entry } from "node-geocoder";

export interface ExtendedEntry extends Entry {

    extra?: {
        googlePlaceId?: string;
        confidence?: number;
        neighborhood?: string;
    };

}
```

Originally, the entry object does contain extra information, but extra information does not contain neighborhood, even though it should.